# fetch string between two words from a page in php

Tags: php, substring

I have a string like:

```
Q1. What is the value of 2+3? o1. 5 o2. 6 o3. None o4. All the Above Category : Maths Subcategory : Algebra Attribute : Skill Test Correct Option : 1 Q2. What is the value of 10+30? o1. 40 o2. 60 o3. None o4. All the Above Category : Maths Subcategory : Algebra Attribute : Skill Test Correct Option : 1
```

Now I want to create one array containing two elements :

```
What is the value of 2+3?

What is the value of 10+30?
```

that means basically the text between Q1.to o1. and Q2. to o1.
I have tried in php like:

```
preg_match('/Q1(.*?)o1/', $contents2,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

where $contents2 is the above mentioned string value.

Please help me.

Comment: The pattern is allways 'What' at the beginning and '?' at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your regex:

```
preg_match_all('/Q[0-9]+?\.\s([^\?]+\?)/', $contents2, $matches);
```

Your strings will be in `$matches[1]`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "Q1. What is the value of 2+3?"
    [1]=>
    string(31) "Q2. What is the value of 10+30?"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "What is the value of 2+3?"
    [1]=>
    string(27) "What is the value of 10+30?"
  }
}
```

Assumptions:

- The question is always preceded with `Q##.` where `##` is any combination of numbers.
- The question always ends with a `?` mark.

Regex breakdown:

- `Q[0-9]+?` - Match starts with the letter Q, followed by 1 or more characters that are digits between `0` and `9`. Non-greedy with `?`.
- `\.` - a period `.` follows the `Q##` portion of the match
- `\s` -  a space follows the period `.` portion of the match
- `(` - begin a group selection
- `[^\?]+` - match one or more characters that are *not* a `?` character (the `\` escapes the regex character)
- `\?` - include the question mark at the end of the match
- `)` - end of group selection

Bonus: in case the question is not phrased with a `?` mark at the very end (e.g. "What is 2 + 2? Pick the correct answer."), to instead match to the consistent `o1` following the question, you can use:

```
preg_match_all('/Q[0-9]+?\.\s(.+?)o1/', $contents2, $matches);
```

This strategy instead matches *any* character after the `Q##.` in a non-greedy manner until the `o1` portion been found. It's intentionally left out of the group so the matches don't contain the `o1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. definitely this will help you:

```
$string = "Q1. What is the value of 2+3? o1. 5 o2. 6 o3. None o4. All the Above Category : Maths Subcategory : Algebra Attribute : Skill Test Correct Option : 1 Q2. What is the value of 10+30? o1. 40 o2. 60 o3. None o4. All the Above Category : Maths Subcategory : Algebra Attribute : Skill Test Correct Option : 1";

$temp_array = NULL;
$final_array = NULL;

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

//determine number of question mark
$number_of_question_mark = substr_count($string , "?");

for($i=0;$i<$number_of_question_mark;$i++){
       $temp_array[$i] = get_string_between($string, "What is the value of", "?");

       //replace the search string
       preg_replace('/What is the value of/', '', $string, 1);
       preg_replace('/?/', '', $string, 1);

}


foreach($temp_array as $key=>$value){
    $final_array[$key] = "What is the value of ".$value."?";
}

print_r($final_array);// this is the result
```